# 2011 MacBook Pro won't turn on

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, macos

Although the problem is quite common, after googling for several hours I didn't find an appropriate solution for my particular case.

I got a 2011 MacBook pro with the latest OS (El Capitan) and it has the following problems.

1. After several minutes of inactivity it hibernates and eventually I can't turn it back on. It only shows a black display and doesn't respond to any action. Thanks to the power button I can only turn it off.
2. Turning on the mac requires me 20 minutes of trial and error. I have to try almost 15 times to boot it. It gets stuck on a progress bar screen which doesn't go further than 50%. Sometimes the progress bar is gone and a white blank screen appears. I have tried to boot with safe mode and the same thing happens.

I am worried that this can be a hardware problem. If that's not the case how can I "cure" this strange behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely the issue explained on [this page](http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/) on apple.com. If so, it is a problem with your GPU.

Symptom wise the "trial and error" in trying to start up your computer corresponds to my own experience, which I have also seen online. I personally also didn't see any actual graphics glitches before experiencing my first trouble startup up my computer. Only when my computer was already in a pretty bad state, did I see them.

I am quite sure I have this issue on my other computer, because using a third party program [gfxCardStatus](https://gfx.io/) I was able to avoid crashes when I switched to "Integrated Only", which is the internal GPU. That avoids using the GPU that has the problem.
Note that you may have to act quickly to get reimbursed for a repair. The final date is Februari 27 for this issue.

More info

http://mbp2011.org/